# Transaction fail error

Tags: tokens, nft, erc-1155

When I add the following line -

```
require(msg.value > 0.1 ether);
```

I get the following error -

```
Gas estimation errored with the following message (see below). The transaction execution will likely fail. Do you want to force sending?
execution reverted
```

What is the cause of it and how can I resolve it?

This is my full smart contract -

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;

import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC1155/ERC1155.sol";
import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/utils/Strings.sol";
import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/utils/Counters.sol";


contract Tokens is ERC1155 {

using Counters for Counters.Counter;
Counters.Counter private _tokenIds;

constructor() ERC1155("https://ipfs.io/ipfs/bafybeic3yphboh7wtzr6rr4zz/NFT{id}") {
}

function uri(uint256 tokenId) override public pure returns (string memory) {

    return(
        string(abi.encodePacked(
            "https://ipfs.io/ipfs/bafybeic3yphboh7wtzr6rr4zz/NFT",
            Strings.toString(tokenId),
            ".jpg"
        ))
    );
}

function mintNFT(uint256 amount) public returns (uint256)
{
    _tokenIds.increment();
    uint256 newItemId = _tokenIds.current();
    _mint(msg.sender, newItemId, amount, "");
    return newItemId;
}

function purchaseNFT(address from, uint id, uint amount) public payable {
    require(ERC1155.balanceOf(from, id) >= amount);
    require(msg.value > 1 ether);
    ERC1155.safeTransferFrom(from, msg.sender, id, amount, "");
}

function approve(address to) public
{
    ERC1155.setApprovalForAll(to, true);
}
```

}

Comment: Could you share more of your code?

Comment: @Sky - I have added the full contract

Answer (score 1):

Your smart contract code works. Possibly your problem when adding this condition:

```
require(msg.value > 0.1 ether);
```

is that you don't set the value inside `msg.value` textbox present in **DEPLOY & RUN TRANSACTIONS** below **VALUE** textbox in REMIX IDE. In summary when you'll call `purchaseNft()` you must set value inside **value** textbox (see this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pRrUY.png)).
I made a improvement in your function, in particular you can see the following code:

```
function purchaseNFT(address to, uint id, uint amount) public payable {
        address from = msg.sender;
        require(ERC1155.balanceOf(from, id) >= amount, "Error on balanceOf() line!");
        require(msg.value > 0.1 ether, "Error on check msg.value line!");
        ERC1155.safeTransferFrom(from, to, id, amount, "");
    }
```

I set `msg.sender` into `from` variable because when you wrote ERC1155.safeTransferFrom(from, msg.sender, id, amount, ""); in your smart contract code, the value about `msg.sender` is your smart contract address and not user wallet address.